# sfdx cli assign role to user

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

Is there a way to assign a role to some user with sfdx cli command?

In my existing tests, i create community user, and the user running the tests must be assigned to some role, else, i have the following error

```
UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION, portal account owner must have a role: []
```

So, i have to to assign a role to my user running the tests;

Thank you;

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000175522&type=1) on how to avoid this error in test class. I don't think this is related to dx though. It's more on your test data creation.

Comment: @JayantDas thanks for your reply, i already saw the 2 links, and the proposed solution to avoid the error it to run tests with test user,
What i want is to leave tests unchanged, and assign role by cli command (this will resolve my issue)

Comment: You won't be able to achieve what you are trying to do with sfdx. sfdx is a "tool" to facilitate your build, it cannot manipulate data that you are creating within your test class. What you need here is to "have proper" data within an already written test class, which won't be possible using sfdx.

Comment: @JayantDas i don't want manipulate any data, i just want to assign role to some scratch org user, exactly like what we can do with permission set with **'force:user:permset:assign'** command

Comment: I don't think you can do that. However - let's say even if you are able to achieve this, your test class can still have a different user's context with a combination of test user creation and using *runAs*. And in that case, your test class will still fail.

Comment: @JayantDas we don't have any runAs in our test classes (And we will never have, we use different approach to do our tests), tests are always ran by admin user that has a role, thank you JayantDas

Comment: Late to the party, but I would say this is not a duplicate because it asks for a way to add a role to a user via SFDX CLI.